# Swift, actor: Actor-isolated property 'scanning' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context

Tags: swift, actor, swift-concurrency

I have an actor:

```
actor StatesActor {

    var job1sActive:Bool = false
    ...

}
```

I have an object that uses that actor:

```
class MyObj {
    
    let myStates = StatesActor()
    
    func job1() async {
    
        myStates.job1IsActive = true

    }
}
```

Line:

`myStates.job1IsActive = true`

errors out with this error:

> Actor-isolated property 'job1IsActive' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context

How can I use an actor to store/read state information correctly so the MyObj can use it to read and set state?

Comment: Create a function within your actor that updates the property. Then `MyObj` should call that function.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> How can I use an actor to store/read state information correctly so the MyObj can use it to read and set state?

You cannot mutate an actor's instance variables from outside the actor. That is the *whole point of actors!*

Instead, give the actor a *method* that sets its *own* instance variable. You will then be able to call that method (with `await`).

Comment: ture. I needed to wrap that in a method in StatesActor.... thank you.

Comment: Basically the actor is _teaching_ you how to use multithreading safely.

Comment: Async property setters are in theory possible. Swift just doesn't have them yet.

Comment: `await MainActor.run { ... set your lovely property here ... }`

Comment: Up until today, when I installed Xcode 14b4, I was able to write `await myActor.foo = bar` without issue.

Comment: I had a non-actor model with a @MainActor property so this worked:
```Task { @MainActor in
               CODE
        }```

Answer (score 6):

It is not allowed to use property setters from code that is not run on the actor ("actor isolated code" is the exact terminology). The best place to mutate the state of an actor is from code inside the actor itself. In your case:

```
actor StatesActor {
    var job1IsActive: Bool = false
    func startJob1() {
        job1IsActive = true
        ...
    }
}
class MyObj {
    let myStates = StatesActor()
    func job1() async {
        await myStates.startJob1()
    }
}
```

Async property setters are in theory possible, but are unsafe. Which is probably why Swift doesn't have them. It would make it too easy to write something like `if await actor.a == nil { await actor.a = "Something" }`, where `actor.a` can change between calls to the getter and setter.

The answer above works 99% of the time (and is enough for the question that was asked). However, there are cases when the state of an actor needs to be mutated from code outside the actor. For the `MainActor`, use `MainActor.run(body:)`. For global actors, `@NameOfActor` can be applied to a function (and can be used to define a `run` function similar to the `MainActor`). In other cases, the `isolated` keyword can be used in front of an actor parameter of a function:

```
func job1() async {
    await myStates.startJob1()
    let update: (isolated StatesActor) -> Void = { states in
        states.job1IsActive = true
    }
    await update(myStates)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more generic method that allows you to modify property in any way you want within one call on actor isolated level.

```
extension Actor {
  func isolated<T: Sendable>(_ closure: (isolated Self) -> T) -> T {
    return closure(self)
  }
}
```

And use it

```
actor StatesActor {
  var job1IsActive: Bool = false
}
class MyObj {
    let myStates = StatesActor()
    func job1() async {
      await myStates.isolated { 
        // this call will be done on actor isolated level
        $0.job1IsActive = false 
      }
    }
}
```